# clients.matchAll() gives error "Cannot find name 'clients'" in typescript

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

Trying to implement the example offered by google here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/

```
async function hasOffscreenDocument(path) {
   // Check all windows controlled by the service worker to see if one 
   // of them is the offscreen document with the given path
   const offscreenUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL(path);
   const matchedClients = await clients.matchAll();
   for (const client of matchedClients) {
     if (client.url === offscreenUrl) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```

but I'm getting a typescript error

`Cannot find name 'clients'.ts(2304)`

I even tried adding "clients" in types in tsconfig.json but nothing happen.

Comment: Do you have https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed long time ago and declared in ts config `"types": ["node", "jest", "chrome"]`

Comment: And where are `clients` supposed to come from? I didn't find it in API reference? If this is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/matchAll then you should add `webworker` to `tsconfig.types`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Thanks for the help. Just need to fix the last error `Property 'offscreen' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.ts(2339)`

By the way, the code I've written is from the official google documentation, it's not something I'm trying to invent here.

Comment: You need to have both `chrome` and `webworker`, I think it should work

Comment: Seems like the install wasn't installing the latest version of chrome types and that's why I had the chrome.offset error, altough I had `"@types/chrome": "^0.0.208"` in package.json. Installed the latest version and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Managed to find a fix for this here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14877

in my case, what worked is:

```
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
```

in my utils file, where I was calling the function

```
  const matchedClients = await self.clients.matchAll()
```

and add `webworker` in compiler options in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["dom", "es2021", "webworker"]
  }
}
```